# jquery ui - Strange scrollbar behaviour when dragging items from draggable to sortable

Tags: jquery-ui, scrollbar, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

If you click and drag an item from draggable list to the sortable list, the browser's scrollbar will grow or shrink depending on how far right your cursor goes.
If you drag off the end of the window, the window will scroll off to the right.

Not sure, why is this happening!
Anybody has any ideas?

Comment: That is the default behavior and not strange, If you won't to stop that, you should set the body(or container) overflows to hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

specify a [containment](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-containment) option in which your element can be dragged around

Comment: I used containment option but still no luck. It still does show the scrollbar!

Comment: then it means that your body must be having a width of 100%. try giving a fixed width to your body and specify the body in the containment option